# Merge two lists with dataframes into one list with merged dataframes

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have two lists of data frames: listA and listB. How to get a list of merged dataframes (listC)?

```
dfA1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("a", "b"), y1 = c(1, 2), row.names = c("1", "2"))
dfA2 <- data.frame(x1 = c("c", "d"), y1 = c(3, 4), row.names = c("1", "3"))
dfB1 <- data.frame(x2 = c("c", "d"), y2 = c(3, 4), row.names = c("1", "2"))
dfB2 <- data.frame(x2 = c("e", "f"), y2 = c(5, 6), row.names = c("2", "3"))

listA <- list(dfA1, dfA2) # first input list
listB <- list(dfB1, dfB2) # second input list

m1 <- merge(dfA1, dfB1, by = 0, all = T)
m2 <- merge(dfA2, dfB2, by = 0, all = T)
listC <- list(m1, m2) # desired output list
```

Comment: Isn't  `listC` already there?

Comment: It's just hard-coded example.

Comment: I think you need to use `Map`  or `mapply`

Comment: like `mapply(merge,listA,listB)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found following solution:

```
listC <- mapply(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = 0, all = T), x = listA, y = listB, SIMPLIFY = F)
```